# Php Excel Reader

Tags: magento2, import

I had made a custom module for product Import via Xls and xlsx.

Path is :: `\Productimport\Controller\Adminhtml\ProductImport`
i have placed PHPExcel folder and 2 other files here.

In controller I am accessing

```
$inputFileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $dir_val = dirname(__FILE__);
            require_once $dir_val.'/IOFactory.php';
            $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
```

this is giving error

> a:4:{i:0;s:197:"Source class
>   "\Fliplearn\Productimport\Controller\Adminhtml\ProductImport\PHPExcel_IO"
>   for
>   "Fliplearn\Productimport\Controller\Adminhtml\ProductImport\PHPExcel_IOFactory"
>   generation does not exist.";i:1;s:6455:"#0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\market-release\educomp-online\App\EOL\marketplace\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php(112):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('Fliplearn\Produ...',
>   Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Factory))

Please give me a solution how can i use this.

Comment: Vishwas Bhatnagar, did you find an answer for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

As Magento 2 is working with Namespaces, you should add backslashes in front of class names. Use `\PHPExcel_IOFactory` instead of `PHPExcel_IOFactory`.